# Undefined Reference to prandom_u32

Tags: android, undefined-behavior

Getting an error while building kernel for Android to enable randomized wifi macaddress. The language added is this:

```
if (randomize_mac && (changes & IFF_UP) && !(old_flags & IFF_UP)) {
    /* randomize MAC whenever interface is brought up */
    struct sockaddr sa;
    unsigned int mac4;
    unsigned short mac2;

    mac4 = prandom_u32();
    mac2 = prandom_u32();
    memcpy(sa.sa_data, &mac4, sizeof(mac4));
    memcpy((char *)sa.sa_data + sizeof(mac4), &mac2, sizeof(mac2));
    if (!is_valid_ether_addr(sa.sa_data))
        sa.sa_data[5] = 1;
    sa.sa_data[0] &= 0xFC;
    sa.sa_family = dev->type;
    dev_set_mac_address(dev, &sa);
}

return ret;
```

}`

I have added the following at the top:

```
u32 prandom_u32(void);
```

But still getting the error. Please help

Answer (score 0):

OK. Solved it: just looked at /include/linux/random.h and found that u32 was defined as random32. So, I have changed the corresponding lines to

```
    mac4 = random32();
    mac2 = random32();
```